# I Forget to upload screenshots of my iOS universal app

Tags: ios

I submitted my iOS universal apps binary to apple iTunes appstore, but i forgot to put screen-shots of my app, is it possible to upload now since my app is still in review process its not yet approved.
Any help is thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add/edit/remove the screenshots at any time from itunesconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it from itunesconnect website.